# Haskell: Where to find debug trace output on Windows10

Tags: haskell

I am using `trace` for debugging on Windows 10, and the terminal states that `Logs printed to console`, but I have no idea where to find this output.

Comment: If your app works in `WINDOWS` subsystem, then you are out of luck.

Comment: Are you running your program from a command prompt window / terminal window / console window (or whatever that is called on windows)?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.21.1. And I have a workaround: I simply add unit tests that test for the values of interest, which for now are 'show' strings, and I test against an empty string -- and the test result shows me the actual.

Comment: If your issue is specifically with Visual Studio Code (plus, I presume, one of the Haskell plugins for it), please [edit] your question and its title to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, *console* in Windows means the *standard output stream*. You can easily see trance output if you're running GHCi in the Windows Command Prompt, as this session demonstrates:

```
C:\Users\mark>stack ghci

Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\ghci7560\ghci-script
Prelude> :m +Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> foo x = trace "foo" x
Prelude Debug.Trace> foo 42
foo
42
```

Here, I'm using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org) to run Haskell, but IIRC, you can use the Haskell Platform for Windows in the same way.